# Iterating over javascript objects with handlebars

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, handlebars.js

I am trying to register helpers with Handlebars to allow iterating over JSON objects.  [This gist](https://gist.github.com/1371586) looked like an appropriate solution.  I converted that into the following CoffeeScript.  Nothing seems to happen when I use either of the helpers (that holds true for both vanilla JavaScript and the CoffeeScript version).  Any ideas?

```
$ ->
  Handlebars.registerHelper "key_value", (obj, fn)->
    buffer = ""
    key 
    for key in obj 
      if obj.hasOwnProperty(key)
        buffer += fn({key: key, value: obj[key]})
    buffer

  Handlebars.registerHelper "each_with_key", (obj, fn)->
    context
    buffer = ""
    key 
    keyName = fn.hash.key
    for key in obj 
      if obj.hasOwnProperty(key)
        context = obj[key]
        if keyName
          context[keyName] = key 
          buffer += fn(context)
    buffer
```

In the template:

```
{{#key_value categories}}
I'M ALIVE!!
{{/key_value}}

{{#each_with_key categories key="category_id"}}
I'M ALIVE!!
{{/each_with_key}}
```

I am currently using `gem 'handlebars-assets'` in the Gemfile to add handlebars to a rails app.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your JavaScript to CoffeeScript transliteration is broken. You don't use `for ... in` to iterate over an object in CoffeeScript, you use [`for k, v of ...`](http://coffeescript.org/#loops):

> Use `of` to signal comprehension over the properties of an object instead of the values in an array.

This CoffeeScript loop:

```
for x in y
    ...
```

becomes this JavaScript:

```
for (_i = 0, _len = y.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
  x = a[_i];
  ...
}
```

So if `y` is an object without a `length` property, then `_len` will be `undefined` and the JavaScript `for(;;)` loop won't iterate at all.

You should also be using `own` instead of `hasOwnProperty`:

> If you would like to iterate over just the keys that are defined on the object itself, by adding a `hasOwnProperty` check to avoid properties that may be interited from the prototype, use `for own key, value of object`.

but that's more for convenience than correctness.

Also, CoffeeScript loops are expressions so you'd usually say `array = expr for own k, v in o` or the equivalent form:

```
array = for own k, v in o
    expr
```

if `expr` is more than one line or too long to allow for a readable comprehension.

A correct and more idiomatic version of your helpers in CoffeeScript would look more like this:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper "key_value", (obj, fn)->
    (fn(key: key, value: value) for own key, value of obj).join('')

Handlebars.registerHelper "each_with_key", (obj, fn)->
    key_name = fn.hash.key
    buffer   = for own key, value of obj
        value[key_name] = key
        fn(value)
    buffer.join('')
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/LWTPv/