# Display all or selected properties of an object using Meteor & Handlebars

Tags: javascript, meteor, handlebars.js

I trying to make jobboard app using meteor. I am able to fetch data from db and display them in a template. But for that i am retrieving each property in the template now. Was there any way that i can display all or some of the properties at once.

```
Template.postSubmit.events({
    'click #submit': function(event){
        var job = {};
        job.jobtype = $('input[name ="jobtype"]:checked').val();
        job.category = $('input[name="category"]:checked').val();
        job.location = $('input[name="location"]').val();
        job.relocationAssistanceAvailable = $('input[name="relocationAssistanceAvailable"]')[0].checked;
        job.description = $('#jobDescription').val();
        }
});

//****Return data***//
Template.postDisplay.posts = function(){
    return Jobs.find();
}

//**My template where I am retriving data**//
<template name="postDisplay">
    <div class="container">
        {{#each posts}}
            <li>{{location}}</li>
            <li>{{jobtype}}</li>
            <li>{{category}}</li>
            <li>.......</li>
        {{/each}}
    </div>
</template>
```

CAN SOMEONE HELP ME OUT TO DISPLAY ALL THESE ITEMS IN A COLLECTION WITHOUT RETRIEVING EACH AS ABOVE .
THANKS IN ADVANCE....!!!!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't specifically declare each document property and where/how it is going to be rendered within the html, how are you going to place them and style them? For example, what if you want to display each property in a different line, or a paragraph, or a list item just like you are doing?

That being said, the only way you can get the complete properties is as a JSON representation which is described at http://docs.meteor.com/#ejson_stringify

```
Template.postDisplay.posts = function(){
  return _.each(Jobs.find().fetch(), function(postDocument) {
    return EJSON.stringify(postDocument);
  });
}

<template name="postDisplay">
  <div class="container">
    {{#each posts}}
      {{.}}<br/>
    {{/each}}
  </div>
</template>
```

EJSON also has a delimeter option, which you can hack to actually mimic a `li` element

```
Template.postDisplay.posts = function(){
  return _.each(Jobs.find().fetch(), function(postDocument) {
    return EJSON.stringify(postDocument, {'string': '</li><li>'});
  });
}

<template name="postDisplay">
  <div class="container">
    {{#each posts}}
      <li>{{.}}</li>
    {{/each}}
  </div>
</template>
```

*Side note: you are printing out `<li>` items but not enclosing them within `<ul>` therefore resulting in appearing as a single list. in fact each job post is a different list.*

Comment: Oh, you can perhaps also create a custom handlebars helper as described here https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Handlebars and iterate over the keys using underscore, and then placing it on the document as a block. This will be more complicated than your original code, but if you definitely must insist, I can try to provide an example.

Answer (score 1):

Handlebars can easily iterate over arrays, as you've probably seen with the `{{each}}` helper.

What you want is to to iterate over object keys. For that, you need to [register a Handlebars helper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9102068/iterating-over-javascript-objects-with-handlebars).

Anyway, sooner or later you'll want to display some fields in a specific way, even if now they all seem like strings. For example, you might want to hyperlink the location to a Google Maps URL, or the category to a page in your app listing all jobs in that category.

This is why iterating over object keys isn't that common, and I would advise including each field in an `<li>` and moving on with your app.

PS: "NO NEED TO SHOUT....!!!!" :)